# Can't read from newly created .txt. It's being used by another process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, file-io

When I create my `log.txt` with `File.Create(Path.Combine(PATH, NAME));` and then try to read from it I get an exception: `{System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.`.

If the `log.txt` file exits and not created in the method I can read and write to the log wihtout any problems.

Is the `log.txt` created async and the problem is that the program is trying to read it before it's created?

```
public static void WriteToLog(string text)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(PATH))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(PATH);
        }

        if( !File.Exists(Path.Combine(PATH, NAME)) )
        {
            File.Create(Path.Combine(PATH, NAME));
        }

        var logLines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(PATH, NAME)).ToList<string>();
        logLines.Insert(0, "-------------------------------------------------End New Log");
        logLines.Insert(0, text);
        logLines.Insert(0, "-------------------------------------------------Start New Log");
        File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(PATH, NAME), logLines);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your log file is appended to at the head rather than the tail? That's... a rather unusual approach. Every new entry is going to force the *entire* file to be re-written.

Comment: Yes it's not nice to rewrite the entire log, but I don't see a way to avoid it if I want to have the newest logs at the top.

Comment: Easy - change you expectations and place the newest logs at the end - like everyone else does.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I must have it at the top. I don't know if the code is fully optimized. I don't see a way to avoid havent to write it all everytime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File.Create creates a filestream, which is open after the creation. so the file is used by its own process.

just change it to

```
        using(var f = File.Create(Path.Combine(PATH, NAME))) { } ;
```

Comment: It works great thanks. I missed the filestream because this time i didn't used the return value, but still had to consider it, so i won't forget to dispose the stream. Your are my hero for today :)

Answer (score 3):

[`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) has a return value of type [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx). That `FileStream` should be `Close`d (or `Dispose`d) if you do not intend to use it for anything.

For a log file, however, I'd usually create the `FileStream` directly by constructing a `FileStream` object, using one of the [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) that accepts a `FileShare` parameter. That way, you can keep the stream open, but indicate that other programs should be able to open it for reading:

```
var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(PATH, NAME),
   FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
   FileAccess.Write,
   FileShare.Read); //Now other people can access the log file whilst I'm still writing to it
```